# Apache Flink: Metrics with key as label

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

I'm using `PrometheusReporter` on Flink, and have some counters I wanted to export with the key of keyed stream.

I don't have the key on `open`, so I'm trying to do it `processElement` instead, something like:

```java
// job
myStream.keyBy(Foo::getKey)
        .process(new FooOperator())
        .name("foo");

// operator
public class FooOperator extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Foo, Bar> {

  private transient Counter counter;

  @Override
  public void processElement(Foo value, Context ctx, Collector<Bar> out) throws Exception {
    if (counter == null) {
      counter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().addGroup("key", value.getKey()).counter("my_counter"):
    }
    counter.inc()
    out.collect(new Bar(foo));
  }
}
```

But I still get:

```
Name collision: Group already contains a Metric with the name 'my_counter'. Metric will not be reported.
```

Anything I could do? Maybe there is a better way I'm failing to find?

My idea would be to get whatever counter already exists there, but I can't find a way to do it that is not reflection...

Answer (score 1):

A given instance of a `KeyedProcessFunction` is multiplexed across many different keys. The `open` method is called just once, when no specific key is in context, so you can't create a per-key metric there.

I believe there are two problems with what you've tried so far. First, you are going to need to create a separate `Counter` for every distinct key -- not just one per `KeyedProcessFunction` instance. Second, I'm not sure that `addGroup("key", value.getKey())` is going to work here. If you still have problems after fixing the first issue, then maybe try `addGroup("key").addGroup(value.getKey())` instead.

And finally, if your keyspace is large, and especially if it is unbounded, this whole approach is questionable. Flink's metric system isn't designed to scale up to huge numbers of metrics.

Comment: Thanks David! Its not unbounded and its no big (couple of hundred keys at most). My understanding of the `KeyedProcessFunction` was wrong, this is already very helpful. My next idea would be to not key by anything and use a MapState... will try that and let you know.

Comment: MapState kind of works but I still get that error sometimes... I think I'll sink those metrics to a kafka topic and consume and generate metrics outside flink...